# Printing Images with ZPL code

Tags: image, printing, graphics, zpl

I'm using ZDesigner to create my label and generate the zpl code. My label have several text boxes, a barcode, and a logo image.
I used the generated code on this webpage -> http://labelary.com/viewer.html, and the output was fine.
When I send the same zpl code to the printer (GC420D, installed as generic/text only) the logo image it's not printed.
ZDesigner uses the command ^GFA to send the image to the printer, I tried with diferent extensions (.pgn, .jpg and .bmp) and the results is always the same, no logo.

Any ideas why?

generated code:
`^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW570
^LL0320
^LS0
^FO220,170^GFA,8000,0800,00020,:Z64:
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:F9E4^FS
^FT128,67^A0I,12,14^FH\^FDData de Emiss\C6o^FS
^FT128,129^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#DOCUMENT#^FS
^FT76,103^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#VAL#^FS
^FT100,49^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#DE#^FS
^FT255,50^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#CE#^FS
^FT408,46^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#CC#^FS
^FT110,209^A0I,12,16^FH\^FD#Eur#^FS
^FT134,227^A0I,12,16^FH\^FDRecibo n\A7^FS
^FT124,101^A0I,12,16^FH\^FDEur^FS
^FT300,67^A0I,12,19^FH\^FDC\A2digo Entidade^FS
^FT434,67^A0I,14,16^FH\^FDC\A2digo Cliente^FS
^BY2,3,20^FT441,119^BCI,40,Y,N
^FD>;12345678>69^FS
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ`

Answer (score 1):

here is my answer a little late but it may be useful for someone. I had a problem when performing a print service for an android application, when pasting the zpl code into the text editor I was not noticing that for some reason some blank spaces were being added, I realized until I copied the code and I viewed it here http://labelary.com/viewer.html
after that I remove the blank spaces and the image could be displayed

[zpl code with blank spaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NE3r.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31602564)